# Why does ". myscript" return file-not-found in only one Git for Windows sh.exe?

Tags: bash, git, sh, git-bash

I have downloaded Git from [here](https://git-scm.com/download).

I recently discovered there's two copies of sh.exe, which provides a bash shell.

1. `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`
2. `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe`

I have come to discover that there's a difference in functionality between the two.

For example, the #1 instance can run a bash script via: `. myScript.sh` where the #2 instance requires the syntax to be: `. ./myScript.sh` The #2 instance will report a missing file error if the #1 syntax is used, even if the file exists.

1. Why are there two instances?
2. Which one is the "proper" one?
3. Is there any documentation about the differences between these implementations?
4. Is there any strong reason I should not use one or the other?
5. Is the difference in functionality a bug?

Comment: I don't have a copy of Windows handy, but I'd *guess* that one of these (specifically, the one that aims for compatibility with legacy ksh rather than standard-compliance) is a copy of `bash` running in `sh` mode, and the other is a more minimal shell written to the POSIX specification, such as `dash`. If you try running (from another POSIX-y shell) `./sh.exe -c 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"'` in both directories, see if either of them returns a value.

Comment: BTW, in general, describing `sh` as "provid[ing] a bash shell" is... making undue assumptions. Even when `sh` *really is* bash, it turns off a lot of features when called under that name. `sh` should never be assumed to have any feature or functionality beyond those described in the POSIX sh specification; if you want bash features, run `bash yourscript`, not `sh yourscript` (and `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or a similar shebang, not `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: (Similarly, a script written for bash shouldn't have a `.sh` extension... but then, [old-time UNIX folks would tell you that giving executable commands extensions is a bad practice altogether](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why Multiple Shells?

This looks like you have one copy of `dash` (a minimal `/bin/sh` implementation -- fast to start up with few bells and whistles) and one copy of `bash` (a much larger shell with a substantial number of extensions taken from ksh). `bash` disables *some* of its extra features when called under the `sh` name, but not all of them.

One of the "features" bash adds to baseline POSIX sh is searching the current directory for files sourced in with the `.` or `source` commands, rather than searching only the `PATH` as the POSIX sh specification calls for.

---

#### Why Do They Differ? Who's Correct?

The relevant standard is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html; see in particular the first paragraph of the RATIONALE section:

> Some older implementations searched the current directory for the file, even if the value of PATH disallowed it. This behavior was omitted from this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 due to concerns about introducing the susceptibility to trojan horses that the user might be trying to avoid by leaving dot out of PATH .

Older shells searched `.` in addition to directories in the `PATH`. However, for security reasons, the POSIX sh specification does not call for this behavior; a user who doesn't put `.` in the PATH presumably wants to be able to `cd` into directories the content of which they don't control or trust without worrying about typosquatting or other attacks.

Assuming that the directory containing `myscript.sh` is not in the `PATH`, the shell which reports the "file not found" is more strictly compliant than the other.